# Cannot get sound on VM with Pipewire as the server

Tags: server, sound, virtualbox, pulseaudio, alsa

I am having trouble getting sound on Ubuntu VMs when Pipewire is the sound server.  I have tried both Ubuntu Studio 23.10 and Ubuntu Budgie 23.10 installed on VirtualBox - neither will produce sound.  Sound is fine on Ubuntu 22.04, Ubuntu 22.04, Ubuntu Budgie 22.04 and AVLinux using the same VirtualBox. I'm using VirtualBox 6.1 on Ubuntu Studio 22.04.

LANG=C pactl info | grep '^Server Name' gives the output Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.79).

inxi -A gives the output Audio:
Device-1: Intel 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW High Definition Audio
driver: snd_hda_intel
API: ALSA v: k6.5.0-14-lowlatency status: kernel-api
Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.79 status: active

Any suggestions?  I want to be sure I can get sound when I upgrade from Ubuntu Studio 22.04 to 24.04, since I do a lot of music production.